# Why was Rabbi Yitzchok Alfasi known as the Rif - rather than the Ria? (הרי"ף - רבי יצחק אלפסי)

Tags: names, rabbis, acronyms, historical-figures

Rabbi Yitzchok Alfasi was known as the Rif. The Roshei Teivos of his name is רי"א, and as far as I know there is no other historic figure known as the רי"א. Then why was he known as the Rif?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: The "Riaf" is most likely not the Rif, but instead the writer of the Me'or Einayim, R' Yoshiyahu Pinto - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47606&pgnum=3 - http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%95

Comment: R. Yitzchok Abarbanel is referred to as the רי"א.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because "Alfasi" is really "al-Fasi". "Al-Fasi" is Arabic for "the Fezite" (Fez being the city in Morocco where he lived).

So kind of like how the word "of" gets swallowed in "USA", the word "the" got swallowed in "Rif". Wouldn't have made much sense to make his acronym stand for "Rabbi Yitzchak The".

Comment: Curiously, A few years ago I asked the one Rabbi Alfasi we knew, who taught at a Jewish day school in Los Angeles, if he was Sfardic. He answerd in the negative, saying he was Ashkenazic and I believe his family came from Poland. (On the other hand, some years ago, Rabbi Berel Wein was visiting LA, and in a lecture mentioned that he had discovered that in his ancestry, he should have been Sfardic). Go figure -- we are such a mixed up people!